# How to use R to reshape multiple rows to separate columns - long to wide?

Tags: r

I have the following df,

```
ID  event   eventdate1     date2       date3        date4     date5  index1   index2   index3
1   before               1/22/2020  
1   now                              10/20/2017   10/25/2017
1   later   03/02/2020                                                  0         1        0
1   tomo    05/05/2020                                                  0         0        0
```

I would like to reshape this to wide and the expected output is,

```
ID    date2     eventdate1      date3      date4       date5   index1   index2   index3
1   1/22/2020   05/05/2020   10/20/2017   10/25/2017             0         0        0
```

> The eventdate1 is related to event.

> eventdate1 will  always print the last date, i.e for tomo.

> It's the same for index1, index2 and index3. All the other dates will have just one date in column.

> date5 is empty and i hope to keep it empty

I hope to use reshape but any other method would work too.

Comment: Its R...@DaniMesejo

Comment: date2 column is present in the expected output. A lot of rows are empty rows and intend to keep it empty during a reshape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `dplyr` you can try :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(across(eventdate1:index3, ~{
                  x <- .[.!='']
                  if(length(x)) last(x) else ''
                  })) -> result

result

#     ID eventdate1 date2     date3      date4      date5 index1 index2 index3
#  <int> <chr>      <chr>     <chr>      <chr>      <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
#1     1 05/05/2020 1/22/2020 10/20/2017 10/25/2017 ""    0      0      0
```

---

For older version of `dplyr` use :

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(eventdate1:index3), ~{
    x <- .[.!='']
    if(length(x)) last(x) else ''
  }) -> result
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), event = c("before", "now", 
"later", "tomo"), eventdate1 = c("", "", "03/02/2020", "05/05/2020"
), date2 = c("1/22/2020", "", "", ""), date3 = c("", "10/20/2017", 
"", ""), date4 = c("", "10/25/2017", "", ""), date5 = c("", "", 
"", ""), index1 = c("", "", "0", "0"), index2 = c("", "", "1", "0"), 
index3 = c("", "", "0", "0")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Error in UseMethod("group_by_") : no applicable method for 'group_by_' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: @AishwaryaPrabhu Please replace `df` with the name of your dataframe.

Comment: Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: could not find function "across".

Comment: `across` is present in newer version of `dplyr` i.e 1.0.0 or higher. You can update your package with `install.packages('dplyr')` to latest version or see updated answer with `summarise_at`.

Comment: There were a few packages missing but it worked. Thank you. I learned something